# Fatal error in building SQLCipher ('openssl/rand.h' file not found)

Tags: macos, sqlite, osx-elcapitan, sqlcipher

I am trying to build SQLCipher on my mac and getting fatal error after running make.

System : OS X El Capitan
I installed openssl after following [this](http://digitizor.com/install-homebrew-osx-el-capitan/) instruction.

Before running make I statically linked libcrypto.a with command

```
./configure --enable-tempstore=yes CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" \
    LDFLAGS="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a"
```

Error I got

```
sqlite3.c:18280:10: fatal error: 'openssl/rand.h' file not found
#include <openssl/rand.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [sqlite3.lo] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that brew has linked to openssl libraries correctly. Run this command

```
 brew link openssl --force
```

Then try again.

Comment: Thats. I just had to add --overwrite option

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this specifically for a golang library I was trying to install. I was getting the following error when I tried to run `go get github.com/xeodou/go-sqlcipher`:

```
# github.com/xeodou/go-sqlcipher
project/src/github.com/xeodou/go-sqlcipher/sqlite3-binding.c:18280:10: fatal error: 'openssl/rand.h' file not found
```

I fixed this by adding the following to my bash profile:

```
export CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CGO_CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have brew on my machine, but I fixed this error a different way. In Xcode, I went to Preferences->locations->"source trees"-> Click +, set OPENSSL_SRC to "full-path-to-openssl-source"

Answer (score 0):

I did all that, but the thing that worked for me is : `brew reinstall openssl`, of course you should be the owner of /usr/local, to make sure of that : `sudo chown -R username /usr/local`.

Hopefully this will help anyone in need.

Comment: Latest macos versions won't let you change the ownership of `/usr/local`. But you can still change the owner of the subfolders, therefore you should use instead `sudo chown -R username /usr/local/*`